# Changing the x-axis numbers in a facet_grid plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, axis-labels, facet-grid

I'm trying to create a facetted plot with `ggplot2::facet_grid` where I visualize Market capitalizations per Industry. The plots look fine, but I'm struggling with the x-axis numbers. They overwrite each other and turn out unreadable. I'd like to change this, but I have no clue how to change it. Does anybody that knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

I used the following codes to create the graphs:

```r
FigMCInd <- ggplot(data = g, 
                   aes(x = MarketCap, group = SIC, fill = SIC)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", binwidth = 2000) + 
  scale_fill_grey() + 
  theme_bw() +
  xlim(0,5000) + 
  labs(x = "Market Value (in Millions $)", 
       title = "Market Value per Industry")

FigMCInd2 <- FigMCInd + facet_grid(.~SIC)
```

Which yields the following figure for `FigMCInd2`:

[image]

So, I'd like to change the x-axis values, but it might be useful too to put the columns a little different to make the graphs more informative. Now, there is only space for two bars per column, indicating the Market Cap for that particular industry.

Comment: Try adding something like `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 3))` to your `ggplot`. You might need to change the size.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).